# Quotation marks in text file

Tags: bash, unix, sed

I am new to using `Unix` and `R` etc. I am in the process of analysing some data from the `NCBI` website using `GEO 2r` datasets. I have downloaded some data from the website and have it in a text file. However, the data has quotation marks throughout and I am trying to get rid of these but have been unable to do so. The file is called `GSE23182_geo2r.txt` and have used following functions:

```
sed 's/\"//g' GSE23182_geo2r.txt  > GSE23182_geo2r_2.txt
```

and

```
sed 's/\"//g' GSE23182_geo2r.txt
```

and

```
sed "s/\"//g" GSE23182_geo2r.txt
```

and

```
cat GSE23182_geo2r.txt | tr -d '\"' > GSE23182_geo2r_2.txt
```

but none of them have worked and seem to present with the problem: `no such file or directory`

Would be so grateful for any help!!

Thanks

Comment: This does not seem to be related to `sed` or the like - `no such file or directory` says the file is not there. (Can you copy the full error message here? It should contain the name of the file that could not be found.)

Comment: sed 's/\"//g' GSE23182_geo2r.txt  > GSE23182_geo2r_2.txt
sed: GSE23182_geo2r.txt: No such file or directory

Comment: Also, it has made a new file but this text file (GSE23182_geo2r_2.txt) is completely blank.

Comment: Don't use `cat` to use `tr`.  Use a redirect instead: `< input tr -d \"  > output`  or `tr -d '"'`.  Escaping inside single quotes is incorrect, and will delete all `\\` from the input.

Comment: As I wrote - this means the original file is not on the current path. You need to supply the full path.

Comment: Concerning the full path - you may need to learn a bit about how to use that. Say, you saved the file onto the Desktop on Ubuntu or something similar, the path then would be `~/Desktop/GSE23182_geo2r.txt` (or equivalently `$HOME/Desktop/...`).

Answer (score 1):

File 'test' contains lots of " 
The contents of the file are:

```
$ cat test 
hi " this is a a quote"
"'"starting quote""
```

Now to delete " we use `tr -d` command.

```
$ cat test |tr -d "\""
hi  this is a a quote
'starting quote
```

Now you can re-direct this to another file as under:

```
$ cat test |tr -d "\"" >test1
$ cat test1 
hi  this is a a quote
'starting quote
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple way would be to open the file in vim and issue the command:
:%s/\"//g

This would remove " throughout the file.

Comment: Thank you! Tried downloading vim but not familiar with it. Is there a command you could suggest to me on UNIx? Thanks

Comment: You can try "tr" (translate command). Added the example in a separate answer